# Commit some files while maven release:prepare

Tags: maven, release, commit, prepare

Is it possible to commit some file (no pom.xml) while mvn release:prepare?

In My MultiModul Project I configured the rlease plugin with preparationGoals to change the Version in a sql file.

```
<preparationGoals>clean verify org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.5:parse-version com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.0:replace</preparationGoals>
```

Everything works fine but the changed sql File will not be commited.

The sql File is in a subdirectory of the parent Folder. There are no pom.xml

Comment: **Vote** for [this feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-798)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use now a scm:checkin in the preparationGoals

clean verify org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.5:parse-version com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.0:replace scm:checkin -Dmessage="..." -DworkingDirectory=./.../...

But that is not the same Commit as what the pom.xml 's commited.
This leads to that a mvn rlelease:rollback don't roll back the first commit in preparation goals!

It now look like these :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <tagBase>
                    ......
                </tagBase>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <arguments>-Dtest='*IT,*Test' -DfailIfNoTests=false</arguments>
                <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                <preparationGoals>clean verify org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:parse-version com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:replace scm:checkin -Dmessage="Version in Komponentenversion.sql incrementiert" -DworkingDirectory=./db/include</preparationGoals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Depending on the use case you might want to commit the files during the *completion* of the preparation step. To do so use `<completionGoals>` instead of `<preparationGoals>`. See also 
[documentation](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#completionGoals).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `scm:add` goal. Should work.

More information:

- https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/add-mojo.html
- https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html

Comment: The sql file is already added before release. and Modified after release but not commited.

Comment: <preparationGoals>clean verify org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.5:parse-version com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.0:replace scm:checkin -Dmessage="..." -DworkingDirectory=./.../...</preparationGoals>